# How to print list item use by user using awk

Tags: awk, csh

I have 2 file input file 
input1 is username, tool and number:

```
######
User: a
#####
aem       12
aqwt      24
#####
User: B
#####
aem       34
bwem      52
dd        12
#####
User: C
#####
aem       11
aqwt      2
dd        1
#####
```

input2 is list of tool:

```
aem
aqwt
bwem
dd
```

I want to make output of user and tool and if don't have tool it will assign 0:

```
Tool  a   B   C
aem   12  34  11
aqwt  24  0   2
bwem  0   52  0
dd    0   12  1
```

I have try awk to compare file2 and file1 to print the number but the script will print also line in comment:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1 in a); {print $2} !($1 in a); {print "0"}' input2 input1
```

the output will be:

```
0
0
0
12
24
0
0
0
34
52
12
0
0
0
11
2
1
0
```

Anyone know how to seperate it by column and make it skip the comment line? im new in this languag, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {                                   # process "input2"
        tool[FNR] = $0                          # store the tool name in an array "tool"
        ntool = FNR                             # count of tools
        next                                    # skip the following statements
    }

    /^User:/ {                                  # "User" line in "input1"
        gsub(/[^:]+: */, "")                    # extract the username
        user[++nuser] = $0                      # store the user name in an array "user"
        next
    }

    !/^#/ {                                     # non-comment line in "input1"
        num[$1, nuser] = $2                     # store the number in an array "num"
    }

    END {
        printf "Tool"                           # print the header line
        for (j = 1; j <= nuser; j++) {          # print the user names
            printf("\t%s", user[j])
        }
        print ""

        for (i = 1; i <= ntool; i++) {          # print the body lines
            printf("%s", tool[i])               # print the tool name
            for (j = 1; j <= nuser; j++) {
                printf("\t%d", num[tool[i], j]) # print the number indexed by tool name and nuser
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' input2 input1
```

Output:

```
Tool    a       B       C
aem     12      34      11
aqwt    24      0       2
bwem    0       52      0
dd      0       12      1
```

As the elements of array `num[]` is printed by using the `%d` format, the undefined value is printed as `0`.

Explanation of `gsub(/[^:]+: */, "")`:

- If the format of the `User` line is assured that it has a whitespace
  after the colon such as `User: a`, it is easy to extract the user name
  by just using the variable `$2`.
- I may be overthinking but I considered the case there are no whitespaces
  after the colon such as `User:a`.
- The first argument `/[^:]+: */` in the statement `gsub(/[^:]+: */, "")`
  is a regex which matches non-colon characters followed by a colon
  and possible (0 or more) whitespaces.
- The `gsub()` statement replaces the above matched subsring with the
  second argument `""` (null string) then the remaining portion is
  the name what we want, which is held by `$0`.
- The appropriate function might be `sub()`, not `gsub()`,
  although there is no difference in this case.

Comment: can use explain me what is ++ mean in ```user[++nuser] = $0```

Comment: I want to index the array `user` by number to be printed in the appearance order.
the variable `nuser` is used as the number. The operator `++nuser` increments the
number by one starting from `1`. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: i have put your code but it say :/ Event not found @@ i don't know why

Comment: As you provided your awk command in your question, I had assumed you know how to run an awk script. Run my code as a shell script, or save the code as a file such as `my.awk` and invoke `sh my.awk` (in case of Unix and its variants including Linux and MacOS).

Comment: Thank you i had run your code but the output seem little wrong
```
Tool      a      b      c

aem     12    34    11
aqwt    0      2
bwem  0
dd
```

Comment: The first and second line is correct but from the the third line is wrong
The third line is : ```aqwt   0    2     ```` and the C don't have any value

Comment: What is your `awk` version? It will be shown with `awk --version`. In addition what is the OS you work with? And please make sure each line does not have DOS line ending (CR LF).

Comment: BTW how did you create the script? Did you copy & paste my posted answer `as is`? Or did you type it by hand?

Comment: my version is awk 3.1.5, and i type it by hand

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I suspect you typed `for (j = i; j <= nuser; j++)` instead of `for (j = 1; j <= nuser; j++)` in the lower part of the `END` block.

Comment: that's right thank you so much XD

Comment: Good to know it works now. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry but last question can you explain me the line 
```
gsub(/[^:]+: */, "")
```
 if you have free time thank you again

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer adding the explanation. Hope it helps.